# Search PHP Array Values and Display them if they exist

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two pages, an HTML, and PHP page. The HTML contains a form that asks a user to type a City name and how they want to sort it (none, ascending, or descending).
The PHP page receives the input and contains an array of cities. My question is: how can I display the values (using a loop) that exist in the array if the input contains part of the string?
Ex: if I search "De", it should return Detroit and Dearborn and sort them based on how I choose.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
        $sort = substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'sort', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,4);
        $city = substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'city', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,20);
          $cities[0] = "Detroit, Michigan";
          $cities[1] = "Rome, Italy";
          $cities[2] = "New York, New York";
          $cities[3] = "Austin, Texas";
          $cities[4] = "Atlanta, Georgia";
          $cities[5] = "Dubai, UAE";
          $cities[6] = "Shanghai, China";
          $cities[7] = "Mumbai, India";
          $cities[8] = "Windsor, Canada";
          $cities[9] = "Los Angeles, California";
          $cities[10] = "Chicago, Illinois";
          $cities[11] = "London, England";
          $cities[12] = "Dearborn, Michigan";
          $cities[13] = "Istanbul, Turkey";
          $cities[14] = "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania";
          $cities[15] = "Cincinnati, Ohio";
          $cities[16] = "Anaheim, California";
          $cities[17] = "Orlando, Florida";
          $cities[18] = "Dallas, Texas";
          $cities[19] = "Hong Kong, China";
          $cities[20] = "Cairo, Egypt";
?>
```

Comment: Please do not deface your post if you want them to be deleted. Either delete them yourself by pressing the "delete" button below the tags on your post, or flag for a moderator explaining why you want to have this post deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a [fnmatch()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) check seems a logical approach:

```
$matches = array_filter(
    $cities,
    function($value) use ($city) {
        return fnmatch('*'.$city.'*', $value, FNM_CASEFOLD);
    }
);
```

**EDIT**

Explanation... array_filter() executes the callback against each value in the array ($cities) and that callback returns a boolean true/false to indicate whether it should be accepted or discarded. The callback uses the fnmatch() function to execute a wildcard comparison against the array entry value against your search value; if the value matches, then it returns a true; else it returns a false.

The result; the $matches array contains only those entries that match your search criteria.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZoSkv)

If you want the result ($matches) sorted; then sort it after running that filter

Comment: This will provide the values, not just the keys

Comment: Then display the values of the array, and don't display the keys..... `foreach($matches as $cityName) { echo $cityName, PHP_EOL; }`

Answer (score 0):

First, you can filter your cities with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$filtered = array_filter($cities, function($current) use ($city) {
    // If the current city start with our input, we keep it.
    return stripos($current, $city) === 0;
});
```

Second, you can sort your cities with [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) [`rsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) depending of the order.

```
if ($sort === 'ASC') {
    sort($filtered);
} elseif ($sort === 'DESC') {
    rsort($filtered);
}
```

And then, you just have to return your filtered and ordered results.

Comment: If you don't send a city parameter, $city is null and PHP tell you that `strpos` cannot search for a null value.
When I said return your results, I meant do whatever you want with it, it's an array, so you can iterate over it with `foreach` and display your result, ...

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the array and use the [PHP strstr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to find matches:

```
$matches = array();
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    if (strstr($city, $search)) {
        $matches[] = $city;
    }
}
```